# How to know the amount of memory available for broadcast variables in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a broadcast variable that I am using in pyspark, and I want to know how much space I have available.

I know that a broadcasted variable stays within `spark.executor.memory`, but does it have to fit within the confines of the storage?  Or the confines of the processing?

I know that the `spark.memory.fraction` is what is used for determining the fraction of `spark.executor.memory` used for storage, versus the amount used for processing.  but, say my `spark.executor.memory` is 10GB and `spark.memory.fraction` is `0.75`.

Does the broadcasted variable have to be less than `2.5GB` or less than `5GB`?

this is pyspark 1.6.1.

Also, here is a resource that would be useful as a reference point:  https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/
I do not understand what is "user memory" in that article.

**EDIT** :  As an extension to this question, it would be great to know where the `cached` tables are stored.  Are those in the same place as broadcast variables?  or somewhere different?  It seems to me like those are inside of the `spark.memory.storageFraction`.

Answer (score 2):

Broadcasted variable is stored in the memory of Python process (there is also serialized copy on the JVM). So the part of the memory which is used is the execution memory.

Please remember that PySpark keeps a copy of the variable for each Spark core. So the actual memory limit is closer to

```
(`spark.executor.memory` * `spark.memory.fraction`) / `spark.executor.cores`
```

Comment: Are you sure it is once per core?  I think they are replicated once per executor, see this resource: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/ in the sentence starting "Running tiny executors...".  Do you agree @user9070098 ?

Comment: Also, if it is *execution memory* that is used for broadcasted variables, then  `spark.executor.memory*spark.memory.fraction*(1-spark.memory.storageFraction)` would be the limit from my understanding, at least according to this resource: https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/